# Specifying a variable in ArcMap output if this is not present in the input

Tags: arcmap, vector, buffer, feature-class

I have been using ArcMap 10.6 (working from within a .gdb, with vector files) to buffer selected variables from a number of files (classes of water, buildings, roads and a constructed other for the rest) at different distances (from 100 to 500m) from a defined sampling point in a city (there will be 60 of these points – so 60 points with 5 buffers each). Each buffered sampling point will consist of differing %’s of these variables making up the buffered area. The areas, defining different urban planning indicators, will be used to assess correlation against temperature at each sampling point to see what relationships can be seen at differing distances.

My issue is that I’m exporting this data to Excel and using pivot tables (which I’m familiar with and use quite a bit) to further process the data (min and max, percentages, volumes, etc) and refine into a summary table for graphing. I have the process sorted, however the problem I am having when linking to the pivot table is that, if there is no “water” in the buffered area, this will not be included in the buffered area produced by ArcMap (obviously). This random loss of one of the variables causes issues when summarizing data from the pivot tables, as the ability to do an easy sequential copy and paste link is not available (sometimes it’s there, sometimes not). I can do this manually, checking each link, however this is very time-consuming.

My question is essentially an ArcMap one. Using vector files, can I instruct ArcMap to somehow do the following If/Then - “if there is no water within the buffered area, provide a water class and give it a value of 0”, so this is recorded in the exported data, and each sample site then has 4 discrete classes (roads, buildings, water and other). For example, sample point 1, buffered at 100m, class = water will have an area_sqm = 0 if no water in the buffered area. To get to the final, merged buffers is a multipart process. I am looking at using a lot more variables in future so an easy fix for a missing variable would be great. The process works fine, it’s just this hiccup with the Excel automation, coming off the base ArcMap data. I did a bit of a search but could not find anything related to this issue. Maybe possible in Model Builder or using Python both of which I'm not overly familiar with?

Comment: Cant you create a table with one row for each class and the value of zero then Append this to the real table Before you export it to excel? I would use pandas python library instead of excel, but it will require some Learning if you are not familiar with python. You know of ArcMaps pivot table geoprocessing tool?

Comment: Hi Bera, A manual addition to the tables before export is one option after sorting out which of the 300 sample point buffers don't contain water (a lot do and will have areas calculated). I have used ArcMap pivot tables but much prefer the added flexibility of Excel for the additional processing I need to do. This works fine for everything else. I may need to update with more data and also have this problem with other variables and would prefer an "automated" method if possible. I'll have a bit more of a look at your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, what I've done in Excel is added a list of all 60 sample points (with area_sqm = 0) to the 5 buffer distances in the data used by the pivot table then redone the data source. This picks up water as 0, now has consistently 4 variables, and doesn't affect others. It allows me to quickly use the copy and past to set up all the buffer rows in the first summary sheet. Really only need to use the water but will do all for consistency. Would still like to know if my original query could be done.